# How to append value to map?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-collections-api

How to append this map2 value to map1 ?

Here the sample code: edited for better readability

```
Map<Object,List<Object>> map1;
Map<Object,List<Object>> map2;
Iterator it=somelist.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Object[] obj =(Object[])it.next();
    if(obj[1]>23){
        List ls=new ArrayList();
        ls.add(obj[0]);
        ls.add(obj[1]);
        ls.add(obj[2]);
        map1.put(obj[0],ls);
    }
```

Here the map1 value

```
    else() {
        List ls=new ArrayList();
        ls.add(obj[0]);
        ls.add(obj[1]);
        ls.add(obj[2]);
        map2.put(obj[0],ls);
     }
     map1.putAll(map2);
}
```

I am new to Java, anybody help me

Answer (score 1):

```
map1.putaAll(map2);
```

And be sure to not have duplicate keys in these maps. Otherwise they will be overwrited

Comment: Its Overriding the old one

Comment: Java Map Class Reference:
**An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.**

Comment: Key is different only but still its overriding

Comment: Here is some Sample coding:

Answer (score 0):

You are also need to initiate the maps (currently they are null values) using some collection which suits for cases that you will be able to have duplications or not. Otherwise some data will be missing.